# IndexError: list index out of range in loop

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary, tweepy

I am using Python 3 / Tweepy to create a list that contains the user names associated with various Twitter handles.

My code creates an empty dictionary, loops through the handles in the list to get the user name, saves this info in a dictionary and then appends the dictionary to a new list.

I am getting `IndexError: list index out of range` when I run the code. When I remove the 4th line of the for loop I do not get errors. Any thoughts on how I can resolve the issue? Why is this line of code causing errors? Thanks!

Here is my code:

```
def analyzer():
handles = ['@Nasdaq', '@Apple', '@Microsoft', '@amazon', '@Google', '@facebook', '@GileadSciences', '@intel']
data = []
# Grab twitter handles and append the name to data
for handle in handles:
    data_dict = {}
    tweets = api.user_timeline(handle)
    data_dict['Handle'] = handle
    data_dict['Name'] = tweets[0]['user']['name']
    data.append(data_dict)
```

Comment: Presumably, `api.user_timeline(handle)` is returning an empty list

Comment: Check the length of the `tweets` list before trying to index it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error is occuring beacause of the empty list which you are trying to access with index 0. you can control this by checking if list is empty or not:

```
def analyzer():
handles = ['@Nasdaq', '@Apple', '@Microsoft', '@amazon', '@Google', '@facebook', '@GileadSciences', '@intel']
data = []
# Grab twitter handles and append the name to data
for handle in handles:
    data_dict = {}
    tweets = []
    tweets = api.user_timeline(handle)
    if tweets:
        data_dict['Handle'] = handle
        data_dict['Name'] = tweets[0]['user']['name']
        data.append(data_dict)
```

Answer (score 2):

i guess main issue in below code

```
 tweets = api.user_timeline(handle)
```

api.user_timeline() may returns you empty list and you are trying to access
first element from this empty list.

```
 tweets[0]
```

that's why you are getting 'index out of range' issue.

you can modify your code somthing like this -

```
for handle in handles:
    data_dict = {}
    tweets = api.user_timeline(handle)
    data_dict['Handle'] = handle
    if tweets:
        data_dict['Name'] = tweets[0]['user']['name']
    data.append(data_dict)
```